# Multiple student entry using structure and functions in cpp

Tags: c++, function, struct

I used structure for multiple entry of students. But I am getting error in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Student{
   char stuName[30];
   int stuRollNo;
   int stuAge;
};

void printStudentInfo(struct Student s[]);

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   Student s[i];
   cout<<"Enter Student Name: ";
   cin.getline(s[i].stuName, 30);
   cout<<"Enter Student Roll No: ";
   cin>>s[i].stuRollNo;
   cout<<"Enter Student Age: ";
   cin>>s[i].stuAge;
   printStudentInfo(s[i]);}
   return 0;
}

void printStudentInfo(struct Student s[i]){
   cout<<"Student Record:"<<endl;
   cout<<"Name: "<<s[i].stuName<<endl;
   cout<<"Roll No: "<<s[i].stuRollNo<<endl;
   cout<<"Age: "<<s[i].stuAge;
}
```

**error:**

```
main.cpp:29:25: error: cannot convert ‘Student’ to ‘Student*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void printStudentInfo(Student*)’
    printStudentInfo(s[i]);} 
                         ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:33:40: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
 void printStudentInfo(struct Student s[i]){ 
                                        ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void printStudentInfo(...)’:
main.cpp:35:20: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
    cout<<"Name: "<<s[i].stuName<<endl; 
                    ^
main.cpp:35:22: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
    cout<<"Name: "<<s[i].stuName<<endl;
```

I get the point that I need to define i in the function but how will it take values accordingly. If i take a for loop in the function the values will get printed more than the time required. If i do not take an array it will give a segmentation fault.

Please help me with this code. I am new to c++.

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using? IDE? Compiler?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things incorrect. When using C++ please consider adopting the correct objects such as `std::string` for storing the student name. Also, differently from C, we don't have to specify the `struct` keyword when passing as a function parameter.

Also, the way you were passing the structure to the `printStudentInfo()` function was wrong. Additionally, I suggest against `using namespace std` if possible.

Here follows a minimal correction of your code (please note that it can be further improved, I just got it barely working):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Student{
   std::string stuName;
   int stuRollNo;
   int stuAge;
};

void printStudentInfo(const Student& s);

int main()
{
    Student s[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Enter Student Name: ";

        if (i) std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline(std::cin, s[i].stuName);

        std::cout<<"Enter Student Roll No: ";
        std::cin>>s[i].stuRollNo;

        std::cout<<"Enter Student Age: ";
        std::cin>>s[i].stuAge;

        printStudentInfo(s[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}

void printStudentInfo(const Student& s){
   std::cout<<"Student Record:"<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<"Name: "<<s.stuName<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<"Roll No: "<<s.stuRollNo<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<"Age: "<<s.stuAge<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Good answer! You can explain `if (i) std::cin.ignore();` a bit in detail or add some reference for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- First of all, the code is not indented. Use your IDEs code beautify options or use some online to indent your code. Example: https://codebeautify.org/cpp-formatter-beautifier
- For learning purposes `using namespace std;` is fine. But, try to avoid it in a more serious code. Read this thread for more information: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- In the `Student` type, the members are prefixed with `stu` which is redundant because they're already part of a properly named type i.e. `Student` and would be referenced in the code by meaningful named objects. Simple and direct member names such as `name`, `rollno`, and `age` would suffice.
- The member for student name is a `char` array with a magic number i.e. 30. Try to learn and use [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which is more safe and straightforward. And, always try to avoid magic numbers. Use proper names for magic numbers using `const`, `constexpr` (if C++11 or above), or `#define` macro replacements according to your requirements. For example, `#define NAME_LENGTH 30`.
- In C++, you don't need to use prefix `struct` everywhere reference the type except the definition or a forward declaration. So, `void printStudentInfo(struct Student s[]);` would be `void printStudentInfo(Student s[]);`.
- The function `printStudentInfo` is supposed to print only one object of `Student` type so the subscript operator with argument `s[]` is redundant. The correct type for this argument in this context would be `Student s` i.e. `void printStudentInfo(Stdudent s)`. There are multiple ways to pass arguments to a function in C++ such as pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. In your context, pass-by-reference makes more sense i.e. `void printStudentInfo(const Student& s)`. Read this relevant thread on the subject: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)
- Again, a magic number for array size. Use a constant with a proper name such as `MAX_STUDENTS`.
- In C++, declare and define a loop control variable inside loop:
  `for ( int i = 0; ... )`
- Declare `Student s[i];` outside the loop. In loop, it means that it is being created every time the loop iterates with a new variable size i.e. 0, 1, 2. That is not intended here. Move it outside with a constant as its size e.g. `Student s[MAX_STUDENTS];`. A relevant thread: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). In the future, when you're familiar with STL (Standard Template Library), use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).
- Miscellaneous (you can study as you go along): array initialization, `std::endl` vs `\n`, `unsigned` vs `signed` (for age, rollno, ...), `std::size_t`, etc.

Here's a working example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/Lig_PB)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    int         rollno;
    int         age;
};

void printStudentInfo( const Student& s );

int main()
{
    const int MAX_STUDENTS = 3;
    Student s[MAX_STUDENTS];

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; ++i )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
        std::getline( std::cin, s[i].name );

        std::cout << "Enter Student Roll No: ";
        std::cin >> s[i].rollno;

        std::cout << "Enter Student Age: ";
        std::cin >> s[i].age;

        printStudentInfo( s[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}

void printStudentInfo( const Student& s )
{
    std::cout << "Student Record:\n"
              << "Name    : " << s.name << '\n'
              << "Roll No : " << s.rollno << '\n'
              << "Age     : " << s.age << '\n';
}
```